# Custom domain issue

Tags: google-app-engine

We have added a custom domain to our appengine app. We followed the instructions when we made our changes, but apparently something went wrong and we can't find the way to fix it.

In our google apps appengine tab, the main URL specified is `https://appid.appspot.com`.  That means, however, that all traffic from the domain mappings will be sent to the https url, and of course this won't work. I don't know how this https url ended up there as in the app engine admin console, the app url is `http://appid.appspot.com`.

We haven't find the way to change this url. We have tried to disable this app in google apps but it didn't work, it stays there.

Answer (score 0):

in your `app.ymal`

```
-secure: optional
```

for more details:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html

scroll to `Secure URLs`

Comment: Thanks moguzalp, but we have nothing specified in my appengine-web.xml (we are using java) so it means it should accpet both http and https what is what we want as we need to use https when accessing from our mobile app. What I want to do is link the http version with the custom domain. If I type www.domain.com it should go to http:// appid.appspot.com and now it goes to https:// appid.appspot.com.